# Is there a way to extract the anova results as a table in Word with the significance levels described on the table in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, anova, tukey

I conducted an experiment as factorial design with 3 replicates to investigate the effect of two factors including medium with 3 levels and line with 3 levels on the variables of fresh weight (FW) and dry weight (DW) of toots. I collected data in a table.xlsx.
I want to simultaneously analyze these two variables in factorial design and perform Tukey test and save the results in .docx format. I also want to display the average comparisons of both variables with the help of ggplot2.
My main point is to first present the significance levels on the p-value column and also below the table. And secondly, the results of both variables should be merged in one table in Word.

Answer (score 0):

R Markdown does have the output option of `.docx` so doing the analysis on an RMD file instead of an R Script file would already have the results in Word format if you export it. Then there are packages to help you with *tidying up* the tables. We got `kable`, `kableExtra`, `broom`, etc. [Additional Reading](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/table-other.html)